# Typescript not throwing errors if I use Javascript APIs above my target

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to understand target and lib in tsconfig.json, and I thought I got it, but it isn't behaving like I think it should. If my target is ES2015, and I use `Array.includes`, or `String.replaceAll`, it should complain right? Because those weren't added to ES until versions 2016 and 2021 respectively.

Here's my whole tsconfig, thanks for any insight.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "ES2015"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "target": "es2015",
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "build",
    "webpack.config.js"
  ]
}
```

I tried using Javascript features that should not be supported. Typescript should error to warn me.

Comment: Looks like it's because I've got `@types/node` in my node_modules.